# Why is lambda expression used in DOTween?

Tags: unity-game-engine, lambda, delegates, dotween

I'm using a lambda expression in my C# script in my Unity project to call a function with a parameter when a DOTween callback is called.

It simply looks like this: `animation.OnComplete(() => DestroyOnCompleted(children));`

It works just fine, but I am note sure why a lambda expression is used in this case. I know it has something to do with delegates, but other than that, I'm not too sure; and I would like to explain it to my exam, if I get asked about it.

Could anyone enlighten me? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation](http://dotween.demigiant.com/documentation.php) of DotTween, you see that row:

[image]

Now looking at the [Source Code](https://github.com/Demigiant/dotween/blob/90093a5c775ea22c9b3a2c828557f22a743c2589/_DOTween.Assembly/DOTween/Core/Delegates.cs) of DotTween, you can see the definition of TweenCallback:

```
public delegate void TweenCallback();
```

**So the question now is, what is a *delegate void* in c#?**

A delegate in c# is basically an object that "represent" a function.
But functions are not all the same, they can have parameters in input and return something (or return void).
To understand what kind of function does a delegate represent, try to just remove the keyword **delegate**.

For example, the TweenCallback without the keyboard *delegate* is:

```
public void TweenCaalback()
```

So the delegate represent a void function that has no parameters in input! (And it is Public).

**What does it means *represent a function*?**

It means that this is valid code:

```
void DoNothing()
{

}

TweenCallback x = DoNothing;
x();
```

So you can "assign functions" to a delegate that has the same function signature.
In this case, TweenCallback is a delegate void (), so you can assign to it a void() function.

**What is a lambda?**

A lambda is an expression of that style:
(string name, int age) => { return 3 };

you can read that as "string name and int age go in return 3"

That's a more concise way to describe that function:

```
int AnonymousFunction (string name, int age) {}
```

The main difference is that lambdas do not have any name. If you have not any parameter in input the lambda become like this:

```
() => {return 3;}
```

If you have only one statement inside the {} you are allowed to write it more shortly as

```
() => 3;
```

**Final step**

Is this valid code?

```
void DoNothing()
{

}

TweenCallback x = () => DoNothing();
```

Yes it is! Tween callback is expects a *void ()* function.

`() => DoNothing();` Is a lambda (un-named function) that takes nothing in input and calls some other function. It's the shorter version of `() => {DoNothing();}` that you have to think as `void () {DoNothing();}`

So when writing

```
animation.OnComplete(() => DestroyOnCompleted(children));
```

You are just passing a *void ()* function to OnComplete Method, that makes sense because TweenCallback is a *void ()* delegate.

**Notes**

As you can see, functions and lambdas expression can be converted **implicitly** to delegates. But you have to understand that they are all different things, and in more advanced coding scenarios that distinction is not just pure theory.

Answer (score 2):

Why not? ;)

I don't know that API too much but it seems like it is simply expecting something like

```
OnComplete(TweenCallback callback)
```

where `TweenCallback` from your usage basically seems to equal the `c#` built-in [`Action`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.action) [delegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates) and basically simply a parameter less void

```
public delegate void TweenCallback();
```

so whether you pass in this callback as a [lambda](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions) like

```
animation.OnComplete(() => DestroyOnCompleted(children));
```

or anonymous method using the [`delegate` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/delegate-operator) like

```
animation.OnComplete(delegate { DestroyOnCompleted(children); });
```

or using a method

```
animation.OnComplete(OnCompletedAnimation);
        
...

private void OnCompletedAnimation()
{
    DestroyOnCompleted(children);
}
```

is basically equivalent.

The main difference between the first two and the last one is: **Where does `children` come from?**

The lambda and delegate way allows you to pass in `children` from the current scope variables without having to store it in any field!